# Stata: Look-up and replace under certain condition

Tags: stata

I have a sales transactions dataset that looks like this:

```
id     mode week   pr   choice  y1  y2  y3
75440   1   1642    0       0   1   0   0
75440   2   1642    0       0   0   1   0
75440   3   1642    1       1   0   0   1
138704  1   1642    0       0   1   0   0
138704  2   1642    1       1   0   1   0
138704  3   1642    0       0   0   0   1
```

where each customer is considering 3 alternatives but must choose only one;

id is unique customer id of a customer who made a purchase,

mode is a list of all product choices (1, 2, 3) available to a customer,

week - in which week the purchase took place,

pr is whether the purchase was on promotion (1) or not (0).

choice is customer's choice,

and y1, y2, y3 refers to mode indicating a purchasing alternative.

If you look at the customers 75440 and 138704, they both purchased products 3 and 2, respectively, on promotion (pr=1) during the same week. However, right now, pr doesn't capture the fact that the both products were in fact on promotion during that particular week. How do I create a new variable pr1=0 and replace it with pr1=1 when I want to show that this product was in general on promotion by looking up pr values for each particular week so that the result would look like this:

```
id     mode week   pr   choice  y1  y2  y3  pr1
75440   1   1642    0       0   1   0   0   0
75440   2   1642    0       0   0   1   0   1
75440   3   1642    1       1   0   0   1   1
138704  1   1642    0       0   1   0   0   0
138704  2   1642    1       1   0   1   0   1
138704  3   1642    0       0   0   0   1   1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider this question off-topic because you are simply asking for code. I (and some other users) usually expect the see some coding attempt by the original poster, along with some description of why it's not working for her. The before/after data example is good, but again, no code attempt on your behalf. Something similar happened here: [How to avoid duplication of a certain variable during alternative-specific data organization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24433561/2077064). I will try to help again, but you must consider that you risk not getting any helpful answers if you keep posting questions in this manner.

You can try something like:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id     mode week   pr   choice  y1  y2  y3
75440   1   1642    0       0   1   0   0
75440   2   1642    0       0   0   1   0
75440   3   1642    1       1   0   0   1
138704  1   1642    0       0   1   0   0
138704  2   1642    1       1   0   1   0
138704  3   1642    0       0   0   0   1
end

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

bysort mode week: egen pr1 = max(pr)

*----- list data -----

sort id mode week
list, sepby(id)
```

See `help egen` and `help by`. The latter is fundamental in Stata. See also [Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004), by Nick Cox.

### Edit

Regarding the order of the variables in `bysort varlist:`:

In general, the order in the sorting of the variables can affect your results. In this case, it doesn't. You are only computing maximums per group, and the groups conformed by some *varlist* will always be the same, whatever the order. Below some code that I hope helps with this. (I've added a check with `cf`, which compares all variables for two datasets computed with diferent orders.)

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id     mode week   pr   choice  y1  y2  y3
75440   1   1642    0       0   1   0   0
75440   2   1642    0       0   0   1   0
75440   3   1642    1       1   0   0   1
138704  1   1642    0       0   1   0   0
138704  2   1642    1       1   0   1   0
138704  3   1642    0       0   0   0   1
75440   1   1643    0       0   1   0   0
75440   2   1643    0       0   0   1   0
75440   3   1643    1       1   0   0   1
138704  1   1643    0       0   1   0   0
138704  2   1643    1       1   0   1   0
138704  3   1643    0       0   0   0   1
75440   1   1641    0       0   1   0   0
75440   2   1641    0       0   0   1   0
75440   3   1641    1       1   0   0   1
138704  1   1641    0       0   1   0   0
138704  2   1641    1       1   0   1   0
138704  3   1641    0       0   0   0   1
end

list, sepby(id)

*----- see that (mode week) groups are same as (week mode) groups -----

sort mode week
list, sepby(mode week)

sort week mode
list, sepby(week mode)

*----- compute original -----

bysort mode week: egen pr1 = max(pr)

sort id mode week
list, sepby(id)

tempfile first
save "`first'"

*----- compute with modification -----

drop pr1
bysort week mode: egen pr1 = max(pr)

sort id mode week
list, sepby(id)

*----- check two databases -----

cf _all using "`first'" // if no output, all fine
```

The same principle applies for three or more variables.

Comment: Roberto, do the following codes produce identical information: _bysort **mode week**: egen pr1 = max(pr)_ and _bysort **week mode**: egen pr1 = max(pr)_? And if I have three or more variables like **week mode store** does it affect the results if we change the variables' order of appearance? I initially didn't think it would but one of my co-writers raised this issue. Just want to make sure.

Comment: Thank you Roberto for the explanation!